# Compiling C# DotNet6 App on a Mac with Apple silicon using MSBuild?

Tags: macos, msbuild, apple-silicon

Hi I am moving an IOS project from Xamarin.IOS to DontNet6.
I am also trying to move the build from an Intel Mac mini to an Apple silicon Mac.

I tried real hard not to install rosetta 2 but I had to give in and install it (but that is another issue), now I can build the project on the Apple silicon using the Visual Studio IDE, but I am trying to get the command line working but when I type MSBuild on the command line It says "zsh: command not found: MSBuild".

what do I need to do in order to get msbuild to work on a Mac ?

Regards Christian Stœr Arild Andersen

Comment: You have installed Visual Studio for Mac, correct? Was your terminal session running prior to installing Visual Studio for Mac and if so, have you run `rehash` to pick up changes to `PATH`? Or have you started a new shell session? Does your `PATH` include `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/msbuild`?

Comment: I can compile from the IDE but I have no path (or directory) /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/msbuild
I will try to reinstall and see if that helps but I have my doubts

Comment: I just checked the installer and it looks like every thing was installed ok but I chose not to install Xamarin IOS because I want to move to use dotnet6 only from now on.
I should still be able to compile from the command line without xamarin ios i would have thourght

Comment: Mono.framework and Xamarin.iOS.framework are different. Visual Studio for Mac is based on MonoDevelop (aka Xamarin Studio) and many of the components and tools are still located in the Mono.framework folder.

Comment: You are trying to run the command as `msbuild` and not `MSBuild`, right? Case makes a difference on Unix.

Comment: I know. I have tried both. I have also tried vstool build

Comment: I dont have a mono.framework forlder (or I cant find it).
I did not click the check box install the xamarin ios components of (and I managed to do a ide build with out it)

Comment: I think I am getting somewhere I am using "dotnet msbuild" command and now it gives me the error  "error NETSDK1147: To install these workloads, run the following command: dotnet workload restore" so it is still bad in a better way. the ide showed this error when I first loaded the project and I installed it and it worked but how do I do this from the command Line (oh yes I can feel a nuget for Apple silicone question comming next)

Answer (score 0):

the command I needed to use is

```
dotnet publish
```

that lets me build an **IPA** file for distribution